# prestashop api security

Tags: web-services, security, access-token, prestashop

I'm about to build an iOS e-commerce app. This app will query the prestashop webservice api of an existing prestashop installation.
I've been playing with the prestashop webservice and it seems to work fairly good so far except for lacking of security: there's no token-like architecture that I can use to track authentication of users. Is it me missing something or Prestashop DOES lack this feature?
What would be your approach? Is there any module that I can install and solve this problem? I really really would like to limit as much as possible coding extensions for prestashop by hand.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop web service is secured with an authentication key :
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Chapter+1+-+Creating+Access+to+Back+Office